# Tomcat 8.0.45 JSESSIONID Context Root Cookie Duplicates (1 with trailing slash, 1 without)

Tags: tomcat, session-cookies, tomcat8

Some of my users end up with 2 cookies. Their browsers send both to the server and Tomcat seems to use the 2nd cookie that matches the context root.

How does this happen? How I can stop it?

I only want cookies without the trailing slash to exist.

For example, the browser sends:

```
JSESSIONID with path /foo
JSESSIONID with path /foo/
```

Edit:

Tomcat has variables that affects this. I am not specifying it and I have seen the duplicate cookie issue occur in Chrome.

```
sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash - Some browsers, such as Internet Explorer, Safari and Edge, will send a session cookie for a context with a path of /foo with a request to /foobar in violation of RFC6265. This could expose a session ID from an application deployed at /foo to an application deployed at /foobar. If the application deployed at /foobar is untrusted, this could create a security risk. However, it should be noted that RFC 6265, section 8.5 makes clear that path alone should not be view as sufficient to prevent untrusted applications accessing cookies from other applications. To mitigate this risk, this attribute may be set to true and Tomcat will add a trailing slash to the path associated with the session cookie so, in the above example, the cookie path becomes /foo/. However, with a cookie path of /foo/, browsers will no longer send the cookie with a request to /foo. This should not be a problem unless there is a servlet mapped to /*. In this case this attribute will need to be set to false to disable this feature. The default value for this attribute is false.
```

Comment: If you log-out, are both cookies expired or only one? If you login, is Tomcat sending two cookies or one? Can you capture a protocol trace of Tomcat setting both cookies? If so, please post the full `Set-Cookie` headers you are getting from the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to reproduce it when viewing my browser console. I've only seen both cookies existing in my browser being sent to the server. I'll keep trying to reproduce, though.

Comment: I have the same issue, in my case it's tomcat 9 and Firefox.

Comment: Additional info in my case, the 2 cookies are always created at the same time, and the one with trailing slash has SameSite: "none" while the one without a slash has SameSite: "Strict".

Answer (score 0):

Send the Cookie with the trailing slash in the path with an expiration date in the past. The browser shouldn't send the expired cookie anymore.

Comment: This is how to remove the cookie and, while that could be used to prevent the cookie from ever persisting, it is a bandaid solution and I am looking for what causes it in the first place.